# How to apply GroupJoin properly with aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm a bit old school with using databases and not quite familiar with LINQ. I found a LINQ extension to achieve what I need but I'm stuck with using it properly. it's `GroupJoin`

what I exactly need to do is *"The category & the number of this category with each post"*

[image: Number of the category with each post]

Models

**PostContent**

```
public class PostContent
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string subTitle { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime postDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string post { get; set; }

    public Guid? postCatId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("postCatId")]
    public virtual PostCategory postCategory { get; set; }
}
```

**PostCategory**

```
public class PostCategory
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PostContent> postContents { get; set; }

}
```

My attempt *" but return nothing"*

```
    var NumberOfCategoriesForEachPost = context.postCategories 
    .GroupJoin( context.postContents,
    cat => cat.Id,
    con => con.postCatId, 
    (Category, Content) => new  
    {
        Cate = Category.categoryName,
        Cont = Content.Count()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `LINQ` query it does not specify `group by` on the `categoryName` column. `GroupJoin` seems to be grouping on the joining column.
You can use LINQ to SQL instead, as I find it more readable:

```
var query = from cat context.postCategories
         join con in context.postContents
         on cat.Id equals con.postCatId
         group new {cat, con} by new {cat.categoryName } into g
         select new 
         {
              g.Key.categoryName ,
              Count = g.Select(s => s.con.postCatId).Count()
         };
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it gives me nothing like my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nikhil Patil you inspired me to make it properly.

I found the correct way to do that as follows

```
        var query = from cat in context.postCategories
                    join con in context.postContents
                    on cat.Id equals con.postCatId
                    group new { cat, con } by new { con.postCatId, cat.categoryName } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        //g.Key,
                        CategoryName = g.Key.categoryName,
                        CategoryID = g.Key.postCatId.ToString(),
                        Count = g.Count()
                    };
```

the result

[image: result]